# How can I use conditional statement in min function

Tags: python

```
dpt = [0] * (10**6 + 1)
dpt[1] = 0
dpt[2] = 1
def f(x):
    if dpt[x] != 0:
        return dpt[x]
    else:
        dpt[x] = min(f(x/3) if x%3 == 0 else 9999, f(x/2) if x%2 == 0 else 9999, f(x-1))
        return dpt[x]


N = int(input())
print(f(N))
```

I was practicing Dynamic Programming but ran in to a problem.

```
dpt[x] = min(f(x/3) if x%3 == 0 else 9999, f(x/2) if x%2 == 0 else 9999, f(x-1))
```

In this line, I was expecting this conditional statement would work right but this line makes error.
How can I use conditional statement inside of 'min' or 'max' function?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Barmar, the error is 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float'.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 There's no `key` argument, why do you think that's related?

Comment: I recommend using parentheses or checking the value of x. Maybe it is a float.

Comment: In python, you must do floor division `//` to round to neareast int. Otherwise `x/3` and the like will return a float (even if it is something like 3.0).

Answer (score 3):

Change the line in question to:

`dpt[x] = min(f(x//3) if x%3 == 0 else 9999, f(x//2) if x%2 == 0 else 9999, f(x-1))`

In Python, dividing integers always returns a float, even if the quotient is a divisor. You must either cast the result to an integer with `int()`, or use floor division `//`.

To illustrate this:

```
>>> 11/3
3.6666666666666665
>>> 9/3
3.0
>>> 11//3
3
>>> 9//3
3
>>> int(11/3)
3
>>> int(9/3)
3
```

**Notably, `type(9/3) == float` which is usually a source of mistakes.**

Comment: Thank you so much. It answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know when you need to get an item from the list, you should use an integer or slices.

I mean with an integer is like `dpt[1]` and slices is `dpt[1:2]`.

From your code, you call `f(x/3)` that will return a float. it's makes your code erroring.

```
def f(x):
    if dpt[x] != 0:
        return dpt[x]
    else:
        dpt[x] = min(f(x/3) if x%3 == 0 else 9999, f(x/2) if x%2 == 0 else 9999, f(x-1))
        return dpt[x]
```

The solution is simply to use `min(f(x//3) if x%3 == 0 else 999)` instead only using `/`